# Spring Webflux doOnCancel is not invoked when an app is deployed to Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, spring-webflux

I have a controller with an endpoint that provide a flux like this reported below.
When the app is deployed to kubernetes, methods doOnCancel and doOnTerminate are not invoked.
Locally instead, it works like a charm (when the tab of the browser is closed as instance).

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class TestController {
    ...
    @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> testStream() {
        log.info("Requested test streaming");
        
        return mySink.asFlux()
                .startWith("INIT TEST")
                .doOnCancel(() -> log.info("On cancel"))
                .doOnTerminate(() -> log.info("On terminate"));
    }
    ...
}
```

```
2022-08-06 18:25:42.115  INFO 3685 --- [           main] com.wuase.sinkdemo.SinkDemoApplication   : Starting SinkDemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_252 on aniello-pc with PID 3685 (/home/pc/eclipse-workspace/sink-demo/target/classes started by pc in /home/pc/eclipse-workspace/sink-demo)
2022-08-06 18:25:42.124  INFO 3685 --- [           main] com.wuase.sinkdemo.SinkDemoApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-06 18:25:44.985  INFO 3685 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2022-08-06 18:25:45.018  INFO 3685 --- [           main] com.wuase.sinkdemo.SinkDemoApplication   : Started SinkDemoApplication in 3.737 seconds (JVM running for 5.36)
2022-08-06 18:26:09.706  INFO 3685 --- [or-http-epoll-3] com.wuase.sinkdemo.TestController        : Requested test streaming
2022-08-06 18:26:14.799  INFO 3685 --- [or-http-epoll-3] com.wuase.sinkdemo.TestController        : On cancel
```

Has anyone encountred the same problem?
Any idea about that?

Comment: I add as additional info: the behavior is the same either connecting by port-forward or api gateway

Comment: Did you check that the connection has been terminated? look like that you are missing some kubernet settings for reactive web

Comment: Connections aren't actually closed. What kind of configuration should be done on the kubernetes side?